# Resize only big images to small without changing the height/width ratio

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I have a folder of colourful images in PNG and JPEG. By using `file` in linux, I can see PNG images are all `PNG image data, ... x ..., 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced` where their height and width are different. And JPEG images are all `JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01`. Their size can be up to `500KB`.

I can use `find . -type f -size +10k -exec ls -l {} \;` to list all the images whose size is above `10Kb`.

I can also use `convert input.png -geometry x150 output.png` to resize one image's height to `150px` without changing the height/width ratio. or `mogrify -geometry x150 *` to resize all the images in the folder.

Does anyone know how combine these 2 commands and **resize all the images whose size is above `10Kb`** in the folder?

Comment: Do you want to keep the original pictures and makes small copies?

Comment: It is not necessary to keep the original pictures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that there are only picture files in the current directory. If not, you may specify two commands, one with `-name "*.jpg"` and one with `-name "*.png"`.

Try this command to see which files are selected (avoid destroying files you want to keep),

```
find . -type f -name "*" -size +10k -exec echo mogrify -geometry x150 {} \;
```

and if OK, remove `echo` to use this command to shrink the files that are too big

```
find . -type f -name "*" -size +10k -exec mogrify -geometry x150 {} \;
```

Maybe the 10k size does not match `-geometry x150`, so you should modify it depending on the kind of pictures.

Comment: I think you can omit `-name "*"`.

Comment: @dessert, Yes you are right, but I put it there as a 'placeholder' to show where to insert `-name "*.jpg"` or `-name "*.png"` if necessary to skip other files in the directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

Why not execute the convert from find?

```
find . -type f -size +10k -exec convert {} -geometry x150 {}.png \;
```

You need to `rename` the files from `*.pic.png` to something useful. But it should work.

Comment: Shouldn't this use `mogrify` to in-place change the file, or specify an output file?

Comment: @muru sure, but the in-place way could lead to permanent loss the files when testing/debugging the script

Comment: ...Make a backup. Touch a file... as a time marker. Find by size exec your convert or mogrify. (I use find to make a file list and then use read & identify to loop over and conditionally. Identify to start the geometry math off and mogrify.) Then I can use find with the -newer flag... newer than that touched file to see what got changed.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a folder with your resized images and not touch your original files, and place the resized images there.

This will reserve your original images of which you can replace if you are satisfied with the new resized images.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -d resized ] && mkdir resized

while read image; do
    echo "Resizing [$image] to [resized/$image]"
    convert $image -geometry x150 "resized/$image"
done < <(find . -type f -size +10k -exec ls {} \;)
```